# How to consume mouseClick event if mouse clicked outside JWindow?

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouseevent, jwindow

Right now I'm looking for solution how to restrict/consume `mouseClicked` event if mouse is clicked outside `JWindow`. For example - `JWindow` has two buttons "Yes" and "No" (like dialog). And it's parent also has various buttons - but they must be inactive during `JWindow` (dialog) is visible. Should I restrict parents buttons actions each manually - or maybe there is some better solution?

Comment: so you may have your implemented dialog windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ..some better solution?

A modal dialog.  When a modal dialog is visible, access tot the parent component is blocked.

See [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html) for more details.

Comment: Yes, but I have created custom dialog from scratch using `JWindow`.. So now somehow I need to block access to the parent component. Getting closer :)

Comment: *"I have created custom dialog from scratch using `JWindow`."*  Why?  It sounds like you're trying to make a silk purse from a sow's ear.

Comment: I have better control in that case, but it's not easy sometimes (like creating ComboBox as I remember - but the result is great).

Comment: Do you realize that a dialog has access to [`setUndecorated(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29)?  That makes it look as much like a `Window` as any user could distinguish, but still retain all that handy modal functionality.  Beyond that, my interest in helping someone *recreate* a dialog is ..just about zero.

Comment: Yes, I already did that, everything works fine now. Just that I do not need any methods of `JDialog` except `setModal(true);`.

Comment: *"..except `setModal(true);`"*  That is no small ability.  To reproduce it would be a huge task.

Comment: Indeed, I've read `Dialog` source code. Thanks for help indeed.